# How to define neural network neuron-by-neuron?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

So we want to have a random brain-like neuron mess. Meaning:

- We have AxB inputs and CxD outputs.
- We want to have K (where K >= CxD) neurons that are connected to each other at random.
- Yet so that all K neurons are connected to at least one of AxB inputs,
- And all K neurons are connected to at least one CxD output.

Something like ths (here AxB=5, K=4, CxD=2):

[image]

Operations that neurons shall do are weighted summ + some reduction like LeakyReLu.

So one can imagine that when connection randomnes is controlled so that connections are localised over image patches alike layers of CNN it can produce intresting results.

How one could do such thing (handle neurons one-by-one) in PyTorch?

Comment: Why don't you just use a regular PyTorch net and set the weights of some of the connections to 0, so you just have connections according to your rules? The regular implementation should not be able to recover the weights, so they stay 0 and thus act as if there were no connections between the corresponding neurons.

Comment: @jottbe: optimizer will punish for such unused trainable variables...( (imagine 256^2 base image and at least 10 layers gradually collapsing into 10 variables)

Comment: Why do you think the optimizer will punish such variables? I think l1/l2 regularization at least will have no effect on them, as the weights are zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here: The major issue is how to randomly sample the connections, and a minor issue of how to optimize a sparse linear layer.

As for the minor issue, you can implement a [sparse fully-connected layer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63896270/1714410) based on the linked answer.

As for the random connectivity, you'll have to implement it in a way that there are no "loops"

Comment: Ok, so how one could connect outputs of SC layer with initial source layer via another SC layer?